# How can I change the pin.Address when a user clicks the pin?

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, maps

Trying to change the pin's address value when they click it. From a simple text to a string. (myString is a string with a value) This is the code:

```
pin.Address = "Click for more info";

pin.Clicked += onButtonClicked1;


void onButtonClicked1 (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pin pin = (Pin)sender;

        pin.PropertyChanging (pin.Address, PropertyChangingEventArgs myString);

        Navigation.PushAsync (new DetailPage (pin.Address));
    }

public DetailPage (string theAdress)
```

UPDATED:

```
foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {

                myString = currentItem ["info1"].ToString ();

                    var pin = new Pin ();
                    pin.Address = "Click for more info";

                    pin.Clicked += onButtonClicked1;

                    theMap.Pins.Add (pin);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void onButtonClicked1 (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Pin pin = (Pin)sender;

    pin.Address = myString;

    Navigation.PushAsync (new DetailPage (pin.Address));

}
```

Comment: Damn it works but as I load items from a database I need to create the function inside the foreach loop. Otherwise It takes the same string on every pin i click. Code updated.

Comment: Pin also has a Label property.  Have you considered using that to store the extra piece of data you need?

Comment: Yes, I use that to a different string. So I am trying to find options how to add another item into the pin.

Comment: pin.PropertyChanging  += (sender, e) => {
       pin.Address = myString;
      }; this code works but I cannot put it in my OnButtonClicked1 function because I alrdy use a object sender there.

Comment: I answered the question that you actually asked.  If you really want the answer to a different question, then ask a different question.  Changing the question after you've asked it is just confusing.  I'd suggest "How can I store multiple pieces of info in a single Map Pin?"

Comment: Yea I thought that would solve it. I will ask a new one in 30min then. Thanks for your help as always Jason.